# How to add all files to zip except some file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, zip

I am working on zip and compressed all files.

It is working fine.  The command

```
    archive.bulk([
        { expand: true, cwd: zipDir, src: ['**']}
     ]);
```

My problem is that not to add only one file name 'mimetype'.

How to bulk archive without 'mimetype' file?

Any one assist me?